# Creating few scenarios of main function in C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors, clion

I am creating bigger project and I need 3 or 4 scenarios of main function to test if classes work properly. I created main.cpp file like this

```
 #define TEST2 //INTERACTIVE OR TEST1 OR TEST2 OR TEST3

#include <iostream>

#ifdef INTERACTIVE
#include "interactive.cpp"
#endif
#ifdef TEST1
#include "test1.cpp"
#endif
#ifdef TEST2
#include "test2.cpp"
#endif
#ifdef TEST3
#include "test3.cpp"
#endif
```

and inside every of this test files is something like this

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //Code here
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion it should work, but when I build a project I have the linker error:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Project.dir/test2.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [Project] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Project] Error 2
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How are you building your project? It may be a setup issue in your IDE. Each `main` should be associated with a different "target" so your code isn't built with a bunch of `main`s, since only one is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is you are still compiling the cpp file you include in `main.cpp`  You need to remove all of those from from being built in the solution as yo only want to build `main.cpp`.  If you don't then both cpp files get compiled so they have the same symbols so you get a duplicate symbol error.

Comment: That's right, works perfectly without building those files :D

Comment: @emil Glad to help.